# Migrating content form Drupal 7 to CSV or to another MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have a website that is built long time ago with Drupal 7 that is backed with a MySQL database. I want to rebuild the website with some other framework, however, I want to migrate (export) the data from Drupal or from its database directly.
Is there any known Drupal 7 module that can help me doing this migration? Like exporting the data to another MySQL database with a different structure or even to  CSV file.

I am mainly interested in the content of the website (the nodes data) I do not care about users nor comments (I have only one Admin user).

I have tried to write some script to do the migration manually, but it seems to be a very complex process since Drupal 7 stores the data of each field in a different table, and since there are some fields that have multiple values, reference values or some custom field type this made it even more difficult to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using Node Export module for Drupal 7, it gives a lot of choices to export the nodes, depending on the content types. You can also choose the data format to which you want to export like XML or JSON.

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export